# How? Encrypt and Decrypt user membership passwords in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, encryption, asp.net-membership

We are creating a new site using ASP.NET membership provider for user registration and log in. Our old system encrypted user passwords so that we could recover them if we needed to.

I am having a great deal of trouble figuring out if it is possible to use ASP.NET membership functions to simply encrypt the password when the user registers and then unencrypt it so I can see it.

Documentation for this is neigh non-existant.

I know how to configure Web.config to have it store passwords as encrypted ala
passwordFormat="Encrypted" in the provider and assigning a validationKey in the machineKey, however it seems like the password still gets hashed (though perhaps it is just well encrypted). Either way I cannot decifer how the password can be recovered (by us) if neccessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Storing passwords in recoverable format is a very poor idea. If you can recover them so can anyone who breaks into your server.

You're better off using a standard hash+salt approach and having a password reset mechanism to handle the case where users forget their password.

Comment: This is a possibility. It would be very bad PR if account information ever got out.

Comment: doesn't the ASP.NET membership provider support encrypted passwords by default? This means the password is transmitted in hashed text and stored in the db in hashed format. do you need more than that?

Comment: Just to clarify, ASP.NET membership supports clear, hashed, and encrypted formats out of the box. Hashed is the default and is one way only (the best for most situations). Encrypted allows for the decrypting of the password.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use passwordFormat="Encrypted" rather than passwordFormat="Hashed". Then you can use the [DecryptPassword method of the MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword(v=VS.100).aspx) to decrypt the password when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Web.Security

Public Class PasswordRecovery
    Inherits SqlMembershipProvider

    Public Function GetDecryptedPassword(ByVal password As String) As String
        Try
            Dim _encodedPassword() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(password)
            Dim _bytes() As Byte = DecryptPassword(_encodedPassword)
            If _bytes Is Nothing Then
                Return ""
            Else
                Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_bytes, &H10, _bytes.Length - &H10)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error decrypting password.", ex)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Dim _bytes() As Byte = DecryptPassword(_encodedPassword)
give error cannot find DecryptPassword

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword.aspx) DecryptPassword MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [SQLMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) that MS supplies.  If so then why not use the built-in question and answer functionality to allow the user to reset their password.  Alternatively (or additionally) reset their password for them and email the new one to them.  This way your app can't expose a users password to anyone accidentally.

If you really need to decrypt their passwords then the passwordFormat must be set to "Encrypted".  See [DecryptPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword.aspx) for information on decrypting the password.  For details on how to configure for decryption see the [PasswordFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx), note that it says you must specify the decryptionKey attribute of the machineKey element.

Comment: I am aware of DecryptPassword but I cannot get VWD2010 to recognize it as a method. No matter what references I provide or namespaces I use. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Try using System.Web.Security.Membership.Default.DecryptPassword.  DecryptPassword is part of the MembershipProvider class signature so it has to be there.  Note that System.Web.Security.Membership is a static class that doesn't expose the same methods as the implementing classes.