# Retrieve the password from developer point of the user, which is encrypted by ASP.NET membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using  the ASP.NET membership in my application.
When customers register I need to get the password of the user, is there any algorithm so that I can get the decrypted password.

eg:

1) we will be having set of tables that will be created on `asp.net_membership` where in that we store `userName`, `password`, `password key`, `strength` and `security question`.

```
<membership>`enter code here`
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, `enter code here              `Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="MMMS35.API"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             applicationName="Moose"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="1"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Why should you get those details of the users? The module is made so the users are also protected.

Comment: If you need to get the password at the time of his registration then you can simply get the passwords from the text box in which he enters. If this not the case then explain your scenario?

Comment: the password are not [encrypted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) they are [hashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) the whole point of a hashed password is that it cannot be decrypted (easily). It is [one way encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). As @FeliceM, says the whole point of this is so that you can't farm the users passwords.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How? Encrypt and Decrypt user membership passwords in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017301/how-encrypt-and-decrypt-user-membership-passwords-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When customers register I need to get the password of the user, is there any algorithm so that I can get the decrypted password.

If you want to get the password entered by the user *when he is registering*, you can probably do so.  For example, if you use the ASP.NET `CreateUserWizard` control, you can access the `CreateUserWizard.Password` property.  Nevertheless, it's not very clear what you'd want to do with it.

If you want to get the user's password after he's registered, which is probably not a good idea from a security perspective as noted in the comments to your question, you need to configure your MembershipProvider with:

```
enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
passwordFormat="Clear" or "Encrypted"
```